# C++ policy objects and the builder pattern

Tags: c++, c++11, builder-pattern, policy-based-design

I have some class `Builder` which builds an `Object`.  I have plans to replace some of the `Object`'s guts with policy objects, for example being able to set some container type `Storage`.  Specifically, I'd like to use the `Builder` to set policy objects of the `Object`, falling back to some default if none are specified; off the top of my head, something like so:

```
class Builder {
public
    Builder();

    // ... builder methods

    template<typename S>
    Builder& storage() { Storage = S; }

    Object init() { return Object<Storage>(...); }

private:
    typedef std::vector Storage;
}

template<typename Storage>
class Object { ... }

Object o = Builder()
    .storage<std::list>()
    .init()
```

The crux of the question is: can I use a typedef as a sort of "template variable" so I can store a user defined template variable?

To provide some more context, the `Builder` has to support creating a fairly complicated `Object` from a json config file, delegating each key and its validation to an individual method.  I have a static named constructor `Builder::from_config(...)` and a method `Builder::load_config(...)` that do that for me, but I want to support picking the policy object from the config file.  Otherwise I would be fine with just adding templates to the `Builder::init()` method so I could pass my policy objects to the `Object`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand what you exactly want but...

> The crux of the question is: can I use a typedef as a sort of "template variable" so I can store a user defined template variable?

I don't think so; a type can be a template parameter, not a variable; so a typedef is a fixed entity and (as far I know) can't be changed.

Moreover:

```
typedef std::vector Storage;
```

doesn't work because `std::vector<int>` is a type but `std::vector` isn't.

But `std::vector` can be a template-template parameter.

The best I can imagine, to help you, is a internal template struct `Storage` with a template-template parameter.

The following is a compilable example

```
#include <list>

template <template <typename ...> class C>
class Object
 { };

class Builder 
 {
   private:
      template <template <typename...> class C>
      struct Storage
       { Object<C> init() { return Object<C>{}; } };

   public:
      Builder ()
       { }

      template <template <typename...> class C>
      Storage<C> & storage() { static Storage<C> ret{}; return ret; }
 };

int main ()
 {
   auto o = Builder{}.storage<std::list>().init();

   static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(o), Object<std::list>>{}, "!");
 }
```

Comment: Thank you very much!  This essentially answers my question.  I need the ability to pick a poilcy from a json config file; in other words, I need to supply a different parameter based on the value of a string, but I want to do it within the `Builder`'s `load_config` method.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just

```
template <template<class...> class StorageT>
class Builder
{
     // ...
    StorageT<Object> storage_;
};

Builder<std::vector>()...;
Builder<std::list>()...;
```

Comment: I need to set the type based on the value of a key in a json file, otherwise I would just have `builder.init<Policy>();`